# I'm stuck dangling from a post in Remember Me

Tags: remember-me

In Remember Me I jumped onto a post thing sticking out from a wall and cannot get off/down from it.  I've tried every key.   Is there a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I vaguelly remembered that I had bound 'Enter' to 'Interact' and that Interact was how to drop from ledges.  Even though the key was still bound, Enter was doing nothing.  So I decided to re-bind it.   That did the trick.

So if you get stuck with the same issue,  try re-binding your keys (even if they are already bound correctly.  'Remember Me' seems to 'forget' things)

Comment: Oh, the irony..

Comment: Didn't see the irony until you mentioned it :)